# Drupal: How to update database from Select Option

Tags: database, forms, select, drupal, drupal-7

Hei guys, I'm really new to Drupal and am stuck right now by having selected all the data I need from my database and get to display it inside a drop down list.
Unfortunatly I have no clue on how I can update my database with this specific selected field, as I am not having any value....

```
$options = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
$options["name"] = array(
$result->name,
);
}

$options2 = array();
foreach ($results_tour as $result2) {
$options2[$result2->sku] = array(
$result2->title,
    );
    }

$form['tour'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => $options2,
);

$form['tour_guide'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Tour Guide'),
'#options' => $options,
'#description' => 'Please select a guide for this specific tour'
);

$form['save'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' =>  'Speichern',
'#submit' =>  array('plantours_form_submit'),
);

return $form;

}

function plantours_form_submit($form, $form_state) {

db_update('commerce_line_item')
->fields(array(
'status' => $options["name"]
))
->execute();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it manually, by writing directly to database, but use Drupal commerce api (I guess you are using drupal commerce):

https://www.drupal.org/node/1288414